# Shipment Time in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Can the shipment date in Acumatica be extended to include the time component?
At the database level it's a DateTime field however at the DAC field level it is defined as PXDBDate.

I tried to customize the DAC field and replace the attribute as PXDBDateAndTime but it's failing validation.

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
      [PXNonInstantiatedExtension]
  public class SO_SOShipment_ExistingColumn : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment>
  {
      #region ShipDate  
      [PXDBDateAndTime()]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = shipDate.DisplayName, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
      [PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate))]
      public DateTime? ShipDate { get; set; }
      #endregion
  }
}
```

error CS0103: The name 'shipDate' does not exist in the current context

Has anyone tried this and do you have any suggestions for me on how to accomplish capturing the shipment time?

Comment: To fix the error you just need to indicate the display name properly from the SOShipment class using this: PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.shipDate.DisplayName vs just shipDate.DisplayName; What you have will display the date and time in the field however i think the PXDateTimeEdit is either Date or Time not both for edit of the value. At least from what I can remember from past experience but have not spent much time to figure that out. I don't know any date and time edit screen example in Acumatica either. Usually they are 2 separate fields for entry.

Comment: Thanks @Brendan. The Display Name indeed was the issue. I did not notice that despite being right in front of my eyes. :)  Once I updated it, it now works. Thanks for your help.